# Travis CI for private repositories

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, travis-ci

Is there any way to setup [Travis CI](http://travis-ci.org/) on our own machines for private repositories and have it connect to our own git server?

Comment: http://vzmind.tumblr.com/post/9412611799/why-travis  See the section on Installing Travis-CI locally.

Comment: Another alternative is to use a different hosted CI service - such as https://circleci.com

Comment: @PaulBiggar and that helps how...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run travis-ci locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053657/how-to-run-travis-ci-locally)

Comment: Mirror link for the Tumblr post : http://web.archive.org/web/20150228133610/http://vzmind.tumblr.com/post/9412611799/why-travis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like they are working on private repository support. It's in private beta testing now. Checkout this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/travis-ci/Asq30ulew4E

**Update:**
You can also check https://circleci.com/ for private repos.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is [gitlab-ci](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci). This works well with [gitlabhq](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq) and is open source.

**UPDATE:**

I have recently tried [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) with [GitlabHQ](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq). They both can co-exist very well too, but with the help of additional plugins. [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) does not come with support for git out of the box, but a plugin is readily available for that.

Installing [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) was very straight forward on Ubuntu. I am guessing it must be as easy on other platforms as it is written in Java and is available as a .war file. Configuring it is also very easy from its web interface.

Numerous plugins are available (including those for [GitlabHQ](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq), Github etc.). Plugins can be downloaded and installed right from its web interface.

Answer (score 2):

Travis now has a private offering, the starting price at the time of writing this is $129.00 USD per month for unlimited repositories with two simultaneous builds. Very easy to set up and if you're already on GitHub it integrates very nicely: https://magnum.travis-ci.com/

Comment: so then... travis is not opensource

Comment: That's correct, although I don't see where the original poster specifically asked for an open source solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.  I especially like only paying for build time.
http://beta.travis-ci.com/?r=http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/travis-pro/

Comment: Do I really need to give them my email address before I can even see what they offer?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is also a possible CI tool. cloudbees offers enterprise support.

Answer (score 0):

Travis CI now offers [Travis Pro](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/travis-pro/) for private repositories. Users with a student email address can sign up for [GitHub's Student Developer Pack](https://education.github.com/) and [get access to build from private repositories for free](https://education.travis-ci.com).