# How to run travis-ci locally

Tags: travis-ci

I'd rather not have to push every little change to `.travis.yml` and every little change I make to the source in order to run the build.  With jenkins you can download jenkins and run locally.  Does travis offer something like this?

> Note: I've seen the travis-ci cli and downloaded it, but all it seems
> to do is call their API, which then connects to my GitHub repo, so if
> I don't push, it won't matter that I restart the last build.

Comment: You should be able to run the tests locally without having to run Travis CI. Check out the "script" section of the .travis.yml to see what command to run.

Comment: But merely running the tests is not the problem — often a Travis build fails because of setup and install steps in the `install:` section, and it is probably these that the question is more concerned about.

Comment: I'll add that in complex projects a variety of reasons (e.g. different point releases or system interactions of the runtime, intrinsically time-sentitive tests e.g. timeout tests ecc.) the tests themselves sometimes can behave differently on a local environment and on Travis CI.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

This process allows you to completely reproduce any Travis build job on your computer. Also, you can interrupt the process at any time and debug. Below is an example where I perfectly reproduce the results of [job #191.1 on php-school/cli-menu](https://travis-ci.org/php-school/cli-menu/jobs/345582274)
.

## Prerequisites

- You have public repo on GitHub
- You ran at least one build on Travis
- [You have Docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/) set up on your computer

## Set up the build environment

Reference: [https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Troubleshooting-Locally-in-a-Docker-Image)

1. Make up your own temporary build ID

   ```
   BUILDID="build-$RANDOM"
   ```
2. View [the build log](https://travis-ci.org/php-school/cli-menu/jobs/345582274), open the show more button for WORKER INFORMATION and find the INSTANCE line, paste it in here and run (replace the tag after the colon [with the newest available one)](https://hub.docker.com/r/travisci/ci-garnet/tags/):

   ```
   INSTANCE="travisci/ci-garnet:packer-1512502276-986baf0"
   ```
3. Run the headless server

   ```
   docker run --name $BUILDID -dit $INSTANCE /sbin/init
   ```
4. Run the attached client

   ```
   docker exec -it $BUILDID bash -l
   ```

## Run the job

Now you are now inside your Travis environment. Run `su - travis` to begin.

This step is well defined but it is more tedious and manual. You will find every command that Travis runs in the environment. To do this, look for for everything in the right column which has a tag like <kbd>0.03s</kbd>.

[image]

On the left side you will see the actual commands. Run those commands, in order.

## Result

Now is a good time to run the `history` command. You can restart the process and replay those commands to run the same test against an updated code base.

- If your repo is private: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "YOUR EMAIL REGISTERED IN GITHUB"` then `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and [click here](https://github.com/settings/keys) to add a key
- FYI: you can `git pull` from inside docker to load commits from your dev box before you push them to GitHub
- If you want to change the commands Travis runs then it is YOUR responsibility to figure out how that translates back into a working `.travis.yml`.
- I don't know how to clean up the Docker environment, it looks complicated, maybe this leaks memory

Comment: In the logs under `instance:` I can't see a valid docker image path, just something like `travis-ci-garnet-trusty-1512502259-986baf0`. Tried `travisci/ci-garnet:$INSTANCE` and `travisci/$INSTANCE` - doesn't work, can't find the image. Also just taking the postfix (i.e. `travisci/ci-garnet:packer-1512502259-986baf0`) didn't work.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem – image mentioned in instance info can't be downloaded. Moreover, I've tried `travisci/ci-garnet:packer-1512502276-986baf0` image which is suggested in [Travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#troubleshooting-locally-in-a-docker-image). This one is available, but outdated. For instance, CMake is way older than one available in Travis. No new version of `ci-garnet` has been uploaded to [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/travisci/ci-garnet/tags/) in the last six months, whereas earlier there were many updates per month.

Comment: I see that some people can't get the docker image that their build is running. For me this is still working and I am not sure what is different between our setups. But regarding age of images used on Travis production, yes, they do have dated images on production. There are plenty of issues open on Travis discussing that.

Comment: Your reference link doesn't work anymore - i.e. the 'Running a Container Based Docker Image Locally' section was removed from that page. Perhaps the difference in the instance output was due to not having `sudo: required` set? In a current build of mine I see `travis-ci-sardonyx-xenial-1547455603-2c98a19` which I can map to [travisci/ci-sardonyx:packer-1547455648-2c98a19](https://hub.docker.com/r/travisci/ci-sardonyx/tags)

Comment: for me using the latest version of travisci/ci-garnet on docker hub (travisci/ci-garnet:packer-1515445631-7dfb2e1) did the trick

Comment: If you are working on a language specific instance of travis, you can also use the dedicated image, like the [python one](https://hub.docker.com/r/travisci/ci-python/tags).

Comment: Just to clarify, this CAN be used with a private github/gitlab repo right? (even though the post says public is a prerequisite). Just requires SSH key auth?

Comment: @RoyShilkrot @maxschlepzig You don't need to guess the tag `travis-ci-sardonyx-xenial-1547455603-2c98a19` , Just go to https://github.com/travis-ci/packer-templates and search for the image name, e.g. for `sardonyx` https://github.com/travis-ci/packer-templates/blob/b9e1d49f440cd8ac95218c4e938efd8ca284f5b5/ci-sardonyx.yml#L8, in the file, there is a `docker_tag` line leads you to how the tag is formatted.

Comment: @Cloud you can get the most up-to-date tase in the Docker Hub page.

Comment: All images are at least 2 years old, is this still a valid answer?

Comment: This does not appear to be a valid answer anymore.  The linked documentation is gone and that page does not have a matching question nor can I find anything useful there on running builds locally.

Comment: Instead of "look for for everything in the right column which has a tag like...", I would suggest **taking every line that starts with `$`**. Tags do not reliably match the commands run in the container. Also, I think this answer is a bit outdated regarding how to find the correct image, I could not find anything matching `travis-ci-sardonyx-xenial-1593004276-4d46c6b3`, even on [travisci/ci-sardonyx](https://hub.docker.com/r/travisci/ci-sardonyx). I ended up using `travisci/ci-sardonyx:packer-1547455648-2c98a19` in the comment by @maxschlepzig above, which worked fine for me.

Comment: To get the proper image tag, you can do this (replace with your image name):

`IMGNAME="ci-sardonyx" && `
`DTAG=$(curl -s 'https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/travisci/${IMGNAME}/tags/?page_size=1&page=1&ordering=last_updated' |  jq -r '.results[].name') &&`
`INSTANCE="travisci/ci-sardonyx:$DTAG"`


You are retrieving the latest build tag and using it to create your INSTANCE variable.

Answer (score 170):

Travis-ci offers a new container-based infrastructure that uses docker.   This can be very useful if you're trying to troubleshoot a travis-ci build by reproducing it locally.  This is taken from Travis CI's [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#troubleshooting-locally-in-a-docker-image).

### Troubleshooting Locally in a Docker Image

If you're having trouble tracking down the exact problem in a build it often helps to run the build locally. To do this you need to be using our container based infrastructure (ie, have `sudo: false` in your `.travis.yml`), and to know which Docker image you are using on Travis CI.

#### Running a Container Based Docker Image Locally

1. Download and install the [Docker Engine](https://www.docker.com/get-started).
2. Select an image from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/travisci/). If you're not using a language-specific image pick `ci-ruby`. Open a terminal and start an interactive Docker session using the image URL:

   ```
   docker run -it travisci/ubuntu-ruby:18.04 /bin/bash
   ```
3. Switch to the `travis` user:

   ```
   su - travis
   ```
4. Clone your git repository into the `/` folder of the image.
5. Manually install any dependencies.
6. Manually run your Travis CI build command.

Comment: @DustinGraham, that depends on how the project being built by Travis CI has been configured to build.  In the project I was working on, the build command was configured in the **.travis.yml** file under the **script:** subsection and was `make test`.

Comment: `> Manually install any dependencies`

That sounds like a good way to end up with results that don't match up to the regular Travis builds.

Comment: @Gerry By manually install dependencies, I assume he means manually run the commands you have in your travis configuration file that handle the installation of dependencies. So it's the same commands travis CI would be doing, just not automated.

Comment: For step by step instructions on how to run `travis-build` to get a bash script setting up the build, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38804734/388803)

Comment: The code that TravisCI uses to convert ``.travis.yml`` into the executable ``build.sh`` that's actually run is available: [travis-build](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build)

Comment: I feel like this is the answer to my question somehow but the `Manually tun your Travis CI build command`... Like, what? How? What is it? I have a `.travis.yml` file. I tried [travis-build](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build) but it's a dead end.

Comment: @Brandon Inside your .travis.yml there is usually a script subsection that is invoked by travis to build your source. The point of this answer is to setup a local environment that is identical to the one that travis would be operating on. Next you will invoke these commands yourself instead of relying on travis to run them for you. This way you can see the effects of running each command yourself within this environment - this can yield insight into a build problem one might have at travis that otherwise would not be accessible.

Comment: cloning into `/` doesn't work as user `travis` and there's no need since cloning into `$HOME` (of `travis`) seems much more convenient.

Comment: Hi, folks!
I think this approach can work like a charm, but it's important to remember that this [1] command will only work for `precise` distros, right? For `trusty` distros, I think you should use a different approach, something like this [2] command. Does it make sense? it was already spoken by @ScottMcLeod.


[1]: `docker run -it quay.io/travisci/travis-ruby /bin/bash`
[2]: `docker run --name travis-debug -dit travisci/ci-garnet:packer-1499451976`

Comment: This only works for Linux environments. They don't (and can't) provide MacOS images.

Comment: @ebragaparah the image within the docker container is fully independent of the linux distro and or host operating system. That is the point of docker - to run the same environment on different hosts with very little overhead. The first command should work on any operating system / distro that docker fully supports as it opens up an interactive environment inside of the docker container.  The remaining commands are run within the docker container. This would even work on a MacOS host if one were to install https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/

Comment: @Gerry This fully documents how to "Manually install any dependencies" --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49019950/300224

Comment: To avoid the manual steps you can download the raw log, extract the steps, that start with `$`  (use `sed` or similar tool) and then execute them as the `travis` user. Note: I will contain only the steps up to the failure.

Comment: "Select an image from Docker Hub". Why? In order to reproduce the results from travis-ci.com, the same image needs to be used, not some arbitrary one.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev That's what the documentation at Travis used to say verbatim. I copied the documentation here for your convenience. It appears the documentation has now been updated, and my answer is perhaps growing long in the tooth.

Comment: Note to @ScottMcLeod and readers: the content linked to in the Travis docs at the beginning of the answer, no longer exists at that location.

Comment: For example `travisci/ci-php` image has not been updated for the past 3 years? Is this really the latest PHP image?

Answer (score 89):

**UPDATE: I now have a complete turnkey, all-in-one answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49019950/300224. Only took 3 years to figure out!**

According to the Travis documentation: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci there is a concoction of projects that collude to deliver the Travis CI web service we know and love. The following subset of projects appears to allow local `make test` functionality using the `.travis.yml` in your project:

#### travis-build

[travis-build](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build) creates the build
script for each job. It takes the configuration from the `.travis.yml` file and
creates a `bash` script that is then run in the build environment by
travis-worker.

#### travis-cookbooks

[travis-cookbooks](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks) holds the
[Chef](http://docs.opscode.com/) cookbooks that are used to provision the build environments.

#### travis-worker

[travis-worker](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-worker) is responsible for
running the build scripts in a clean environment. It streams the log output to
travis-logs and pushes state updates (build starting/finishing)
to travis-hub.

(The other subprojects are responsible for communicating with GitHub, their web interface, email, and their API.)

Comment: I believe a project to use just those three components and perform `make test` function would be great. Comment if you'd like to work on that with me.

Comment: I'm interested. Let's talk.

Comment: I would be willing to help out as well.

Comment: There's a thread about this [on the travis repo](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2114).

Comment: GitHub is down today because of DDOS https://github.com/blog/1981-large-scale-ddos-attack-on-github-com This is why we need local testing

Comment: The missing component is how to actually queue a build.

Comment: How do I actually install and run `travis-build`? There are no instructions in the repo.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat did you figure it out?

Comment: @sindhus No, sorry. The only solution I've found is to fork the repo, keep making my changes until Travis works, then copy the config file to the main repo and make one commit. Edit: come to think of it, you could use a temporary branch for that, delete the remote branch once done and rebase/squash commits into one.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Here's a containerized travis-build: https://github.com/thomasleveil/docker-travis-compile.

Comment: @FullDecent Did anything ever come of the idea above?

Comment: Ok, everyone, here is the Gist https://gist.github.com/fulldecent/d84cd1abdcc6930865d1b862c4aed917 Please continue the discussion there and help me improve it.

Comment: @all Ping: you probably want to see the updated answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49019950/300224

Comment: Can the be put into one answer?

Answer (score 24):

Similar to Scott McLeod's but this also generates a bash script to run the steps from the .travis.yml.

## Troubleshooting Locally in Docker with a generated Bash script

```
# choose the image according to the language chosen in .travis.yml
$ docker run -it -u travis quay.io/travisci/travis-jvm /bin/bash

# now that you are in the docker image, switch to the travis user
sudo - travis

# Install a recent ruby (default is 1.9.3)
rvm install 2.3.0
rvm use 2.3.0

# Install travis-build to generate a .sh out of .travis.yml
cd builds
git clone https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build.git
cd travis-build
gem install travis
# to create ~/.travis
travis version
ln -s `pwd` ~/.travis/travis-build
bundle install

# Create project dir, assuming your project is `AUTHOR/PROJECT` on GitHub
cd ~/builds
mkdir AUTHOR
cd AUTHOR
git clone https://github.com/AUTHOR/PROJECT.git
cd PROJECT
# change to the branch or commit you want to investigate
travis compile > ci.sh
# You most likely will need to edit ci.sh as it ignores matrix and env
bash ci.sh
```

Comment: I was able to follow steps down to ```travis # to create ~/.travis```. Travis needs a command to execute.

Comment: I get a failure at the compile phase:

    travis@58427d77982d:~/builds/siq-postgresql-container$ travis compile
    /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/travis-1.8.8/lib/travis/tools/system.rb:79: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/clang-5.0.0/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require': cannot load such file -- travis/support (LoadError)

Comment: `sudo - travis` should be `su - travis`.

Comment: When doing the compile step I get:
````/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- travis/support (LoadError)````

Comment: @BerenddeBoer : If you still haven't figured out this issue: here is the solution to get rid of the issue 


`cd ~/.travis/travis-build/
bundle install
bundler add travis
bundler binstubs travis
cd <REPO_YOU_WANT_TO_RUN_COMPILE_IN>
~/.travis/travis-build/bin/travis compile`

Comment: travis compile nor longer valid ? I see unknown command compile :/ travis -h doesn't show it :////

Comment: with this answer I arrived far, but not working at all. I tried to upgrade bundle/bundler `gem install bundler` and run some commands as other answers say: `bundler add travis` and `bundler binstubs travis` in order to get `travis compile` command work. but when I execute generated `ci.sh`, it seems that there's no Internet connectivity and there are weird errors... I give up...

Answer (score 16):

Use [wwtd (what would travis do)](https://github.com/grosser/wwtd) ruby gem to run tests on your local machine roughly as they would run on travis.

It will recreate the build matrix and run each configuration, great to sanity check setup before pushing.

```
gem i wwtd
wwtd
```

Comment: important note: only `ruby` support

Comment: should be possible to add support for other languages too since it shells out to run steps

Comment: That's sick. Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

**tl;dr** Use image specified at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#troubleshooting-locally-in-a-docker-image in combination with https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build#use-as-addon-for-travis-cli.

---

**EDIT 2019-12-06**

`#troubleshooting-locally-in-a-docker-image` section was replaced by [`#running-builds-in-debug-mode`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#running-builds-in-debug-mode) which also describes how to **[SSH to the job running in the debug mode](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/running-build-in-debug-mode/#connecting-to-the-job-running-in-the-debug-mode)**.

**EDIT 2019-07-26**

`#troubleshooting-locally-in-a-docker-image` section is no longer part of the docs; here's why

- https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/issues/2342

  - https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-10-04-combining-linux-infrastructures
  - https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-11-30-announcing-xenial-build-environment-for-enterprise

Though, it's still in git history: https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/pull/2193.

Look for (quite old, couldn't find newer) image versions at: https://travis-ci.org/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/builds/230889063#L661.

---

I wanted to inspect why [one of the tests in my build](https://travis-ci.org/DusanMadar/PySyncDroid/builds/456173787#L867) failed with an error I din't get locally.

**Worked.**

What actually worked was using the image specified at [Troubleshooting Locally in a Docker Image](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#troubleshooting-locally-in-a-docker-image) docs page. In my case it was `travisci/ci-garnet:packer-1512502276-986baf0`.

I was able to add `travise compile` following steps described at https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build#use-as-addon-for-travis-cli.

```
dm@z580:~$ docker run --name travis-debug -dit travisci/ci-garnet:packer-1512502276-986baf0 /sbin/init
dm@z580:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY                       TAG                          IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
travisci/ci-garnet               packer-1512502276-986baf0    6cbda6a950d3        11 months ago       10.2GB
dm@z580:~$ docker exec -it travis-debug bash -l
root@912e43dbfea4:/# su - travis
travis@912e43dbfea4:~$ cd builds/
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds$ git clone https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds$ cd travis-build
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds/travis-build$ mkdir -p ~/.travis
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds/travis-build$ ln -s $PWD ~/.travis/travis-build
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds/travis-build$ gem install bundler
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds/travis-build$ bundle install --gemfile ~/.travis/travis-build/Gemfile
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds/travis-build$ bundler binstubs travis
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds/travis-build$ cd ..
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://github.com/DusanMadar/PySyncDroid.git DusanMadar/PySyncDroid
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds$ cd DusanMadar/PySyncDroid/
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds/DusanMadar/PySyncDroid$ ~/.travis/travis-build/bin/travis compile > ci.sh
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds/DusanMadar/PySyncDroid$ sed -i 's,--branch\\=\\\x27\\\x27,--branch\\=master,g' ci.sh
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds/DusanMadar/PySyncDroid$ bash ci.sh
```

Everything from `.travis.yml` was executed as expected (dependencies installed, tests ran, ...).

**Note** that before running `bash ci.sh` I had to change `--branch\=\'\'\` to `--branch\=master\` (see the second to last `sed -i ...` command) in `ci.sh`.

If that doesn't work the command bellow will help to identify the target line number and you can edit the line manually.

```
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds/DusanMadar/PySyncDroid$ cat ci.sh | grep -in branch
840:    travis_cmd git\ clone\ --depth\=50\ --branch\=\'\'\ https://github.com/DusanMadar/PySyncDroid.git\ DusanMadar/PySyncDroid --echo --retry --timing
889:export TRAVIS_BRANCH=''
899:export TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH=''
travis@912e43dbfea4:~/builds/DusanMadar/PySyncDroid$
```

**Didn't work.**

Followed the accepted answer for this question but didn't
find the image ([`travis-ci-garnet-trusty-1512502259-986baf0`](https://travis-ci.org/DusanMadar/PySyncDroid/builds/456173787#L4)) mentioned by `instance` at https://hub.docker.com/u/travisci/.

Build [worker version](https://travis-ci.org/DusanMadar/PySyncDroid/builds/456173787#L3) points to [travis-ci/worker commit](https://github.com/travis-ci/worker/tree/a3fda16ed23bf71fcd3711d28e826e51b17d0807) and its [travis-worker-install](https://github.com/travis-ci/worker/blob/a3fda16ed23bf71fcd3711d28e826e51b17d0807/bin/travis-worker-install) references `quay.io/travisci/` as image registry. So I tried it.

```
dm@z580:~$ docker run -it -u travis quay.io/travisci/travis-python /bin/bash
travis@370c23a773c9:/$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
travis@370c23a773c9:/$
dm@z580:~$ docker images 
REPOSITORY                       TAG                          IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
quay.io/travisci/travis-python   latest                       753a216d776c        3 years ago         5.36GB
```

Definitely not Trusty (Ubuntu 14.04) and not small either.

Comment: **Worked** approach did it for me. But additionally I had to set `http_proxy` environment for sake of `git clone`. On default `git clone` throws  `gnutls_handshake` exception. So I hat to enforce installation of particular `bundler` version `gem install bundler -v 1.16.6` because `bundler binstubs travis` failed previously. Improve required `bundler` version by running ` bundle info travis`

Comment: This is the best Answer here, because it explains how to compile `travis.yml` into an executable shell script. Nicely done! The only improvement to this would be a mechanism by which to avoid the manual string replacement when specifying the branch from which to build.

Comment: @BenJohnson I've added a `sed` command which addresses the point you made. See the command before running `bash ci.sh`.

Comment: The link * Troubleshooting Locally in a Docker Image* doesn't work anymore

Comment: @juliangonzalez edited with best info I was able to dig.

Comment: after running `bash ci.sh` I get a `Timeout waiting for network availability` error, any idea how fix the error

Comment: Hi, the Ubuntu version 12.04 is so outdated that I encountered apt update errors and openssl issue when installing python, so how to upgrade the Ubuntu version of this images without breaking the ready-travis?

Answer (score 7):

You could try [Trevor](https://github.com/vadimdemedes/trevor), which uses Docker to run your Travis build.

From its description:

> I often need to run tests for multiple versions of Node.js. But I don't want to switch versions manually using n/nvm or push the code to Travis CI just to run the tests.
>
> That's why I created Trevor. It reads .travis.yml and runs tests in all versions you requested, just like Travis CI. Now, you can test before push and keep your git history clean.

Comment: FYI for those looking to try this... doesn't support PHP

Comment: seems to be exclusively for node.js. would be nice to extend it

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what was your original reason for running Travis locally, if you **just** wanted to play with it, then stop reading here as it's irrelevant for you.

If you already have experience with hosted Travis and you want to get the same experience in your own datacenter, read on.

Since **Dec 2014** Travis CI offers an Enterprise on-premises version.

http://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-12-19-introducing-travis-ci-enterprise/

The pricing is part of the article as well:

> The licensing is done per seats, where every license includes 20 users. Pricing starts at $6,000 per license, which includes 20 users and 5 concurrent builds. There's a premium option with unlimited builds for $8,500.

Comment: I was actually interested in this as well. I am trying to configure a travis job for a really awkward project. All those commits on Apr 26 were fiddling with the .travis.yml file (https://github.com/gregturn/issue-aggregator/commits/master). I wish there was an easier way to tinker with the configuration without having to push every single edit.

Comment: @gregturn An ugly but stress-reducing workaround I came up with was to clone my repo to a second GitHub repo.  So the repo `whackamole` is a copy of the project I really want to work on, and I can set up a temporary Travis build job for that project while I work out the kinks of the build automation.  Once I have that nailed down, rebase away the dozens of "oops" commits and push to the real GitHub repo. (And probably remove the `whackamole` GitHub repo and the corresponding Travis job.)

Comment: Wonder if the $6000 license fee is one-time, or yearly.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to use the answers here as-is.  For starters, [as noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354078/5920865), the Travis help document on running jobs locally has been taken down.  All of the blog entries and articles I found are based on that.  The new "debug" mode doesn't appeal to me because I want to avoid the queue times and the Travis infrastructure until I've got some confidence I have gotten somewhere with my changes.

In my case I'm updating a Puppet module and I'm not an expert in Puppet, nor particularly experienced in Ruby, Travis, or their ecosystems.  But I managed to build a workable test image out of tips and ideas in this article and elsewhere, and by examining the Travis CI build logs pretty closely.

I was unable to find recent images matching the names in the CI logs (for example, I could find travisci/ci-sardonyx, but could not find anything with "xenial" or with the same build name).  From the logs it appears images are now transferred via AMQP instead of a mechanism more familiar to me.

I was able to find an image `travsci/ubuntu-ruby:16.04` which matches the OS I'm targeting for my particular case.  It does not have all the components used in the Travis CI, so I built a new one based on this, with some components added to the image and others added in the container at runtime depending on the need.

So I can't offer a clear procedure, sorry.  But what I did, essentially boiled down:

1. Find a recent [Travis CI image in Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/u/travisci) matching your target OS as closely as possible.
2. Clone the repository to a build directory, and launch the container with the build directory mounted as a volume, with the working directory set to the target volume
3. Now the hard work: go through the Travis build log and set up the environment.  In my case, this meant setting up RVM, and then using `bundle` to install the project's dependencies.  RVM appeared to be already present in the Travis environment but I had to install it; everything else came from reproducing the commands in the build log.
4. Run the tests.
5. If the results don't match what you saw in the Travis CI logs, go back to (3) and see where to go.
6. Optionally, create a reusable image.
7. Dev and test locally and then push and hopefully your Travis results will be as expected.

I know this is not concrete and may be obvious, and your mileage will definitely vary, but hopefully this is of some use to somebody.  The Dockerfile and a README for my image are [on GitHub for reference](https://github.com/dleske/travis-ci-xenial-ruby/tree/0bada0bc08b1ada561562e1d6fcc5cce7b4fe665).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to SSH to Travis CI environment via a bounce host. The feature isn't built in Travis CI, but it can be achieved by the following steps.

1. On the bounce host, create `travis` user and ensure that you can SSH to it.
2. Put these lines in the `script:` section of your `.travis.yml` (e.g. at the end).

   ```
   - echo travis:$sshpassword | sudo chpasswd
   - sudo sed -i 's/ChallengeResponseAuthentication no/ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   - sudo service ssh restart
   - sudo apt-get install sshpass
   - sshpass -p $sshpassword ssh -R 9999:localhost:22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no travis@$bouncehostip
   ```

   <sup>Where `$bouncehostip` is the IP/host of your bounce host, and `$sshpassword` is your defined SSH password. These variables can be added as [encrypted variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9338428/55075).</sup>
3. Push the changes. You should be able to make an SSH connection to your bounce host.

Source: [Shell into Travis CI Build Environment](http://web.archive.org/web/20190509132222/https://blog.c-mart.in/posts/shell-into-travis-ci-build-environment).

---

Here is the full example:

```
# use the new container infrastructure
sudo: required
dist: trusty

language: python
python: "2.7"

script:
- echo travis:$sshpassword | sudo chpasswd
- sudo sed -i 's/ChallengeResponseAuthentication no/ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- sudo service ssh restart
- sudo apt-get install sshpass
- sshpass -p $sshpassword ssh -R 9999:localhost:22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no travisci@$bouncehostip
```

See: [`c-mart/travis-shell` at GitHub](https://github.com/c-mart/travis-shell/blob/master/.travis.yml).

---

See also: [How to reproduce a travis-ci build environment for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29753560/55075)