# Can Travis be installed locally like Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have explored and had some good experience with Jenkins. And, Figured out that Travis provides public and private cloud hosted solutions. But, I want to install Travis on my local ubuntu box as in the case of Jenkins.

If we can install Travis locally, kindly post some references for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run travis-ci locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053657/how-to-run-travis-ci-locally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, as someone who's building and operating Travis CI (the platform and product) in production, I can say with confidence that it's been built and optimized to run as a hosted service and not to be installed locally (although our shrinkwrapped Travis CI Enterprise makes that possible).

Comment: Thanks for the short and crispy clarification. i did try the cloud hosted version and fell in love with the ease with which Travis does sync with GIT!