# How to best replicate the Travis CI OS X Build Environment on a local Mac?

Tags: macos, travis-ci

Has anyone replicated the [Travis CI OS X Build Environment](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/) on a local Mac?

We are trying to build a cross-platform collection of binary python packages, and while we have Linux builds on Travis CI, and Windows builds on Appveyor, we have been waitlisted for access to the Travis CI OS X Build Environment.

So we would love to set up a local Mac to replicate the Travis OS X Build Environment.

We see compilers and packages listed here: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/#Compilers-%26-Build-toolchain but I'm wondering if anyone has scripts or tutorials that would help make things easier or avoid problems.

Has anyone done this and have tips?

Comment: Have you read this recently? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053657/how-to-run-travis-ci-locally

Comment: @MaëlPedretti The accepted answer is for the docker (linux) agents. It doesn't seem to refer to the macOS build environment.