# Automate Functional Testing in node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, functional-testing

I checked some NPM libraries to test a webpages or web-services. But all of them expect that the server is already running. Since I want to automate functional testing, how can I setup NPM package in such a way that

1. It can start the server
2. Test the application
3. Stop the server

So that I can test it locally, as well as on online CI tools like travis-ci or circleci.

**Case 1: Webservice**

I wrote a NPM package which starts nodejs HTTP(s) server. It can be started from command line `$stubmatic`. Currently, I use 2 approaches to test it,

1. manual : I manually start it from command line. Then run the tests.
2. Automatic: I use `exec` module to run a unix command which can start the application and run `pkill` command to kill the application. But for this automation, my application need to be installed on testing machine.

**Case 2: Website**

I have create a NPM package: `fast-xml-parser` and created a demo page within the repo so that I can be tested in the browser. To test the demo page, I currently start a local server using `http-server` npm package manually. Test the application.

What can be the better way to write automate functional tests for node js applications?

Note:

- I never used task runners like gulp or grunt. So I'm not sure if they can help in this case.
- In case 1, my application starts node js native HTTP server. I'm not using any 3rd party application like `express` currently.

Comment: I found the solution for case 2. looking for case 1 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1: Webservice**

**Problem 1**
As nodejs `server.close()` was not working. I copied paste this snippet in every test file which is starting my webservice.

```
try{
    server.setup(options);
    server.start();
}catch(err){
    console.log(err);
}
```

Once all the tests are completed, server stops.

**Problem 2
I was using `chai-http` incorrectly. Here is the complete working solution.

```
//Need to be placed before importing chai and chai-http
if (!global.Promise) {
  global.Promise = require('q');
}

var server = require('.././lib/server');
var chai = require('chai')
  , chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

 chai.use(chaiHttp);

try{
    server.setup(someoptions);
    server.start();
}catch(err){
    console.log(err);
}

describe('FT', function () {

  describe('scenario::', function () {

    it('responds to POST', function (done) {
        chai.request("http://localhost:9999")
            .post('/someurl')
            .then(res => {
                expect(res.status).toBe(200);
                //console.log(res.text);
                done();
            }).catch( err => {
                console.log(err);
                done();
            });
    });

});
```

**Case 2: Website** This was quite simple.

- I used `http-server` to start the server so my html files can be accessed.
- I used zombie js for browser testing. (There are many other options available for browser testing)

Here is the code

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

const Browser = require('zombie');
const httpServer = require('http-server');

describe("DemoApp", function() {
  var browser = new Browser({site: 'http://localhost:8080'});
  var server = httpServer.createServer();
  server.listen(8080);

  beforeEach(function(done){
      browser.visit('/', done);
  });

  describe("Parse XML", function() {

    it("should parse xml to json", function(done) {
       browser.pressButton('#submit');
       browser.assert.text('#result', 'some result text');
       done();
    });
   });

   afterEach(function(){
       server.close();
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This question mentions a new Docker container system for Travis that could be duplicated locally.  It might be a way: [How to run travis-ci locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053657/how-to-run-travis-ci-locally)

Comment: Can you plz explain more, how can it help to write/run FTs?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [supertest (SuperAgent driven library for testing HTTP servers)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) and [expect (Assertions library)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect)([documented here](https://github.com/mjackson/expect)) with [mocha (Test Framework)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha)?

I use them and I never had any kind of problems for all the tests I do until now.

The documention in the links contains all the informations you need to build up your test.