# How to run travis-ci locally for Objective-C language

Tags: ios, objective-c, travis-ci

I'm trying to run travis-ci locally.

I'm following this thread: [How to run travis-ci locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053657/how-to-run-travis-ci-locally) and https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Troubleshooting-Locally-in-a-Docker-Image

But I think I chose the wrong image because it hasn't got xcodebuild

Any idea which image should I choose instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can only run the docker images for local debugging. The MacOS images are not docker images, and cannot be used to be run locally. This would also violate license terms of Apple, so this will not happen in the conceivable future.

Comment: Oh I didn't realise about license terms of Apple, sad news then. I would love to have travis running locally