# Set up a local version of Travis CI

Tags: python, django, docker, travis-ci

I am trying to set up some continuous integration utility for a Django python project. The project will use Travis CI, but I also want to be able to do CI locally, for some reason.

My plan is to configure a local Travis. But all resources I can find on the web were written a few years ago, such as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053657/how-to-run-travis-ci-locally) on StackOverflow. Basically, all posts or discussions tell me I should use a Docker image. However, unfortunately, the [official Travis image for python on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/travisci/ci-python) is 3 years old. I don't think it is still being maintained. Is it because there is a new trend, and I am doing the opposite? I don't know what step to take next.

Comment: Last update was made by "meatballhat" try contacting him to get the Dockerfile so that you can update it yourself or you can use the current old image and update it accordingly to match your requirements.

Comment: @sys0dm1n that is a good idea! I will contact the author of the last update.

Comment: happy for you. Good luck